# Creating this covariance matrix manually in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, covariance

I have two samples of 1000 in length each, and I need to construct covariance matrices for these two samples.

Each sample is made up of 10 clusters of size 100. Now, each unit has a variable attached to it that identifies the cluster it came from, and the covariance between two units will be X if they are from the same cluster, or Y if they are from different clusters.

So I need to find a way to construct a covariance matrix that looks like the following picture, except the blocks of X are 100x100 and not 3x3:

[image]

Is there any method of doing this easily? The matrix is far too big to create it by manually inputting the data, and the procedure needs to be repeated thousands of times within a loop.

Comment: The package 'multiwayvcov' has a function for clustered Variance covariance matrices.  If it looks like the one above I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
m <- c(rep(1, 100), rep(0, 300),
   rep(0, 100), rep(1, 100), rep(0, 200),
   rep(0, 200), rep(1, 100), rep(0, 100),
   rep(0, 300), rep(1, 100))
m <- matrix(m, byrow = TRUE)
m
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's far too large to construct that way. The matrices are 1000x1000 containing 10 100x100 boxes of "1's" within them. so using rep() isn't too helpful here :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a straightforward solution requiring no extra packages, so I'll post the solution here in case other people encounter the same problem.

The easiest way for me was to create a double loop that goes through each index of the matrix and manually enters the item. Obviously this is very computationally exhaustive, so if you need to do this many times I'd recommend using a much more efficient approach.

```
    m<-matrix(rep(NA,1000000),ncol=1000)

for(i in 1:1000){
    for(j in 1:1000){
       if(sampleA$cluster[i]==sampleA$cluster[j]){
           m[i,j]<-"X"
           }
       else{
           m[i,j]<-"Y"
   }
}
}
```

Comment: That's a big ol' loop there and might be very slow. You will probably find it much quicker to use `outer`.

Comment: Yep - It's incredibly inefficient, however, I actually need the matrices such that the samples are not in order of cluster (so not nice blocks like the OP). Not sure how to construct such matrices using %o% :\

Comment: probably not `%o%`, but the function `outer` is more flexible than that. You can write the `function(i,j)` you need.